# .bind() jQuery isn't working for me

Tags: jquery, bind

For some reason my simple jquery bind event isn't working. The funny thing is that if I run it in the console of firebug twice it works, but it's very glitchy. Also, when I run it in the firebug console it says this: [Document www.mywebsite.com]

(I placed jquery at bottom before `</body>`)
jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //steps highlighter
$(function() {
    $("div.step_highlighter").bind("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
});

function highlight(evt) {
    $("div.step_highlighter").toggleClass("step_highlighted");  
}
```

html:

```
<div class="step_highlighter">
            <div class="step_wrap">
                    <h2 class="step_title"> Step 1: </h2>
                    <p class="step"> Determine which service we can help you with. </p>
                    <p class="sub_step">Web Design</p>
                    <p class="sub_step">Web Development</p>
                    <p class="sub_step">Graphic Design</p>
                    <p class="sub_step">Internet Marketing</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `mouseover` use `mouseenter` because when you use `mouseover`, moving the mouse on any internal elements trigger `mouseout` and then you see flickering effect. `mouseenter` takes of this issue so always use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` combination.

```
$(function() {
    $("div.step_highlighter").bind("mouseenter mouseleave", highlight);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PtQkg/)**

Comment: I changed it to mouseenter, and it still didn't work. Maybe we're in the right direction though?

Comment: Yeah, and it works fine there. But, I added it on my website, and it still isn't working. I'm not sure what I did wrong, I'm pretty sure everything is exactly the same. If you could just look at it on my web page I think it's all the same... Thank you. www.transcendwebdesign.com

Comment: There is a JavaScript error on your page. [Object [object Object] has no method 'formHighlighter'] in transcendwebdesign.js. Fix that then it should work.

Comment: That's really weird haha... I just deleted that whole script that had an error and you're right it started working. I wonder why... Anyway... The error says it's not a function. How would I go about making it a function haha? Sorry, if it's not simple I'll just start a new question. Thank you so much though you are right.

Comment: That looks like a jQuery plugin. You will have to include its required js file.

Comment: Wow I'm a noob haha. That's interesting though, I didn't include it on the pages that didn't need that plugin (pages without forms) so it couldn't find it, created an error, and somehow messed up other javascript. Well, it's all figured out now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `hover`:

```
$("div.step_highlighter").hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("step_highllighted"); 
});
```

Also, if you're using jQuery 1.7 and above, `.bind()` has been replaced with `.on()`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But I'm trying to learn jQuery, so I want to know what I did wrong with the .bind() also, so that I can use it in the future. Thank you though! : )

Comment: `on` is a new method added in 1.7 it didn't replaced `bind`. `bind` is still available and not deprecated.

Comment: The jQuery API says that `.on()` is preferred to `.bind()` if you're using `1.7` and above: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Try replacing `mouseover` with `mouseenter` in your original script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("div.step_highlighter").bind("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
});

function highlight(evt) {
    $("div.step_highlighter").toggleClass("step_highlighted");  
}
```

The first function isn't doing anything, you have to make it execute itself.... :

```
$(function() {
    $("div.step_highlighter").bind("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
})();
```

And furthermore should just be:

```
$("div.step_highlighter").on("mouseover mouseleave", function(event){
    if(event.type ==="mouseover"){
      $("div.step_highlighter").toggleClass("step_highlighted"); 
    }else{
      $("div.step_highlighter").toggleClass("step_highlighted"); 
      //or what ever else.
    }
});
```

Comment: you may have to get rid of the === and make it == its something you'll have to play with, but on is the most up to date jQuery method for this type of handling, and you should use mouseenter and mouseleave instead of mouseover. I was just trying to give you a little update on jQuery, and using the event that's passed.

Answer (score 0):

Besides use javascript, you could just do this with css. If css can finish the job, just do it with css.

***Eg:***

```
.step_highlighter:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm just trying to learn javascript/jQuery that's all haha... I already know html and css. Thanks though :)